# Phonegap - Android - Status bar notifications

Tags: android, cordova

Is it possible to send status bar notifications to my Android/Phonegap app?  Plus is it reliable/straightforward?

Cheers
Paul

Comment: This has already been answered in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403665/android-phonegap-notification-status-bar-shows-nothing). There's a plugin available for status bar notifications.

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

Comment: possible duplicate of [android phonegap notification status bar shows nothing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403665/android-phonegap-notification-status-bar-shows-nothing)

Comment: http://manijshrestha.wordpress.com/2012/11/23/implementing-android-status-bar-notification-in-phonegapcordova-app/

Comment: @kadaj the link is no longer existing.can u give some other link

Comment: http://plugins.cordova.io/#/org.apache.cordova.statusbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do it in `Android` . Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).

Comment: Yes that's the native solution. But the OP asked how it could be accomplished with PhoneGap.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.