# android phonegap notification status bar shows nothing

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to display a notification msg on android simulator device by using Phonegap plugin called `StatusBarNotification`, [LINK](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification), I followed the instrucations to the word, but when I deploy my application nothing shows in the status bar,

What's confusing me is I do not know where to put my notficiation syntax call which is:

```
window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title here", "Put your message here");
```

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

what about this:

`<a href="#" onclick='window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title here", "Put your message here");return false;'>Click me!</a>`

Put this code into your web page.