# how to have phonegap notification plugin notify periodically

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have been looking for this for hours now and don't seem to be able to find it. I have the phonegap system notification plugin for adroid working;
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/StatusBarNotification

I figured how to use it; [android phonegap notification status bar shows nothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403665/android-phonegap-notification-status-bar-shows-nothing)

I however don't want the users to have to click a link. I would like to have the script to periodically look for new updates. I have tried with `setTimeout` and with `$(document).ready(handler)` but nothing works. I also can't push a notification from the last line of my code (before `</body>`) a trick that works with most javascripts in regular browsers.

So who can help me to get a timer running to push this notification to the statusbar?

Nevermind, I got it to work using the code below. Not sure what went wrong, but probably it is the time of day :)

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    // Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
    setTimeout("notify()",60000);
}

function notify() {
    navigator.notification.beep(1);
    window.plugins.statusBarNotification.notify("Put your title here", "Put your message here");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code. Get timer and set notification at time

```
function updateClock ( ){
 var currentTime = new Date ( );
  var currentHours = currentTime.getHours ( );
  var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes ( );
  var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds ( );
//get timer varialbe

//check. send a notification to update
if(currentHours == ... && currentMinutes  == ...){
  notify();//send notification
}
```

and update timer every second

```
 setInterval('updateClock()', 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use LocalNotification plugin instead of StatusBarNotification.

```
function onDeviceReady() {
// Now safe to use the PhoneGap API
setTimeout("notify()",60000);}

function notify() {
if (typeof plugins !== "undefined") {
                    plugins.localNotification.add({
                        date : new Date(),
                        message : "Phonegap - Local Notification\r\nSubtitle comes after linebreak",
                        ticker : "This is a sample ticker text",
                        repeatDaily : false,
                        id : 4
                });}
```

For more details visit-[Local Notification PhoneGap Plugin for Android](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/LocalNotification)